# i3status memory configuration information doesn't match values in gnome-system-monitor

Tags: window-manager

I have recently installed i3 in Ubuntu 18.04, and I have started configuring the status bar at the bottom of the screen. To do this, I copied the file `/etc/i3status.conf` to `~/.config/i3status/` and changed the name to "config".

The problem I have is that when I check gnome-system-monitor, the values do not match. In gnome-system-monitor, it says 2,7 GiB (73%) of 3.7 GiB, but in my status bar, it says 3,7 GiB total (which does match), 1 GiB available and 2,2 GiB(60%) used, which is not the same as 2,7 GiB.

I am very new to this window manager, and there might be just some simple thing I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Per `man i3status`:

> As Linux' meminfo doesn’t expose the overall memory in use,  there are
> multiple methods to distinguish the actually used memory.
> ...
> Example memory_used_method: classical ("total memory" - "free" -
> "buffers" - "cache", matches gnome system monitor)

In other words, in `~/.config/i3status/config`, find the memory section and specify the `memory_used_method`. Mine looks like:

```
memory {
    memory_used_method = classical    
    format = "Mem: %used" // Or whatever you want. Read the man
}
```

Although I wouldn't be too surprised if they're still not exactly the same, since I think i3status duplicates how gnome system monitor calculates memory, rather than both having a shared source.

You might find it easier to read [the online docs](https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html) rather than the terminal man page. Just remember to make sure the versions match (`i3status -v`).